# openscad If statement issue with variable

Tags: openscad

I have a problem with If statement in OpenScad.
I have 4 variables

```
a=20;
b=14;
w=1;
c=16;
```

I want to check witch number is bigger `a` or `b`.
And after depending who is smaller  to take the value of smaller variable(in our case `b < a`) and to make a simple operation with `c` variable ( `c=b-w`).

I tried like this but it doesn't work.

```
a=20;
b=14;
w=1;
c=16;
if(a>b)
{
    c=b-w;
}

if (a<b)
{
c=a-w;
}

if (a==b)
{
c=a-w;
}
```

It seems logic, but in openscad as I understood you can't change the value of variable inside a If statement. What trick can I use in order to get my goal.
Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OpenSCAD's variable assignment is different. You can only assign variables inside a bracket. So `c = b - w` will only be assigned **inside** the if bracket. Outside if this bracket it will still be 16. Don't ask me why. You can read more in the [Documentation of OpenSCAD](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/General#Variables).

Comment: It's because {...} creates a new scope.  Since that scope doesn't have a value for C you are allowed to assign one.  You aren't changing C's value. You are creating C in that scope. 
 When outside the scope, values created inside are not visible.

Answer (score 14):

in the 3. leg you confused the assignment-operator „=“ with the equal-operator „==“ (correct `if (a==b)`).
in your 3. leg you do the same as in the 2., so you could handle both as an „else“-leg.

Correct: assignment is not allowed in if-statement. In openscad you can use the `?` operator instead:

```
c = a > b ? b-w : a-w;
```

After `=` follows the condition. The statement after the `?` becomes the value if the condition is true, and the statement after the `:` becomes the value if the condition is false. Nested conditions are possible, e.g. your conditions:

```
c = a > b ? b-w : (a < b ? a-w : a-w);
```

More information in the [documentation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/The_OpenSCAD_Language#If_Statement/).

Answer (score -1):

```
c = min(c,min(a,b)/2-w);
```

this also solve the problem )

Comment: this produces an error: WARNING: Ignoring unknown variable 'c'. doesn't  "c = min(a,b) -w" match your question?